# Hive MapReduce Job Submission fails "Target is a directory"

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I've been playing around with Hadoop and it's sister projects, and I've had a few problems along the way, but I've finally hit one that I can not find an answer to:

I have a hive table stored on hdfs as a tab-delimited text file. And I can do a basic select on the table, but as soon as I make the query a little more complicated, hive turns it into a map reduce job which fails with the following stack trace

> 13/11/29 08:31:00 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hduser (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Target /tmp/hadoop-> > yarn/staging/hduser/.staging/job_1385633903169_0013/libjars/lib/lib is a directory
>   13/11/29 08:31:00 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hduser (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Target /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hduser/.staging/job_1385633903169_0013/libjars/lib/lib is a directory
>   java.io.IOException: Target /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hduser/.staging/job_1385633903169_0013/libjars/lib/lib is a directory
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkDest(FileUtil.java:500)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkDest(FileUtil.java:502)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:348)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:338)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:289)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyRemoteFiles(JobSubmitter.java:139)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:212)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:300)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:387)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1268)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1265)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1265)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:562)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:557)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:557)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:548)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:425)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:144)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:151)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:65)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1414)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1192)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1020)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:888)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:781)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
>   Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.IOException(Target /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hduser/.staging/job_1385633903169_0013/libjars/lib/lib is a directory)'
>   13/11/29 08:31:00 ERROR exec.Task: Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.IOException(Target /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hduser/.staging/job_1385633903169_0013/libjars/lib/lib is a directory)'
>   java.io.IOException: Target /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hduser/.staging/job_1385633903169_0013/libjars/lib/lib is a directory
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkDest(FileUtil.java:500)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkDest(FileUtil.java:502)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:348)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:338)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:289)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyRemoteFiles(JobSubmitter.java:139)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:212)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:300)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:387)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1268)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1265)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1265)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:562)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:557)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:557)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:548)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:425)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:144)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:151)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:65)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1414)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1192)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1020)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:888)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:781)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

The folder in question does exist on the dfs, at least the "/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging" part, and no matter what I set it's permissions to, hive or hadoop resets them on a job submission. The really concerning part is that the full path appears to be a generated folder name, so why does the software have a problem with something that it has generated on its own? Why is it a problem that the path is a directory? And what should it rather be?

Edit:
Here is the table I'm working with and the query I'm trying to run:
Query:
`select * from hive_flow_details where node_id = 100 limit 10;`

Table:

> col_name        data_type       comment
>   id                      bigint                  None
>   flow_versions_id        int                     None
>   node_id                 int                     None
>   node_name               string                  None

Bear in mind, this happens to any uery that I attempt that has any kind of a where clause, as hive translates that into an MR job.

Comment: can you post the query you are trying to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually came right with this issue. I found conflicting jars in my classpath which I cleaned, and since then I have had no problems.